# passing ref from sibling

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am using the library [react-native-dropdownaler](https://github.com/testshallpass/react-native-dropdownalert/issues/30) and when I am creating the `ref` for it in `App` instead of adding the component in each screen I want to simply pass its `ref` to my `Router` and use it later. 
the problem with passing its `ref` to the sibling is - they both render together so when I am passing the `ref` its still `undefined`

```
render() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <StatusBar />
       <Router alertRef={this.alertRef}/>
       <DropdownAlert ref={ref => (this.alertRef = ref)} />
    </View>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`createRef`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactcreateref) API to create a `ref`. The `current` property will still not be set until after the first render though.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  alertRef = React.createRef();

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <StatusBar />
        <Router alertRef={this.alertRef} />
        <DropdownAlert ref={this.alertRef} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd pass down the component itself instead and mirror the method in the component:

```
render() {
 return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <StatusBar />
    <Router alertRef={this}/>
    <DropdownAlert ref={ref => (this.alertRef = ref)} />
  </View>
 );
}

alertWithType(type, title, message) {
  this.alertRef.alertWithType(type, title, message);
}
```

Comment: you mind to explain what is going on here? I am a little confused and it doesnt seems to work for me (prob because I am using it wrong)

Comment: in `Router` i tried to test it and `console.log(this.props.alertRef)` to see whats passed to it and its the whole `App` instance but without `alertRef` which make sense because in your example you passed `this` to it

Comment: @obiwankenoobi right, but you can then call `this.props.alertRef.alertWithType("error", "Error", "test")` which you want to achieve after all (aren't you?)

Comment: yes indeed. The problem is when Im am trying to call `this.props.alertRef.alertWithType("error", "Error", "test"` it trow an error `Cannot read property 'alertWithType' of undefined`

Comment: @obiwankenoobi you can't call it in the constructor, it will only be accessible in `componentDidMount`

Comment: yes of course. the error comes from `    this.alertRef.alertWithType(type, title, message)` this line, it happens because we pass the instance `this` before it actually creating `this.alertRef` and therefore its `undefined`

Comment: @obiwankenoobi right, a component will never be accessible before it was mounted, thats what `componentDidMount` is for. If you want to make it work nevertheless you could defer all the calls until the reference is available

Answer (score 0):

The solution I end up with is :

```
class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) 
  super(props)
  this.state = {alertRef:null}

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({alertRef:this.alertRef})
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <StatusBar />
        {this.state.alertRef && (
          <Router
            alertRef={this.state.alertRef}
            language={this.props.language}
          />
        )}
        <DropdownAlert ref={ref => (this.alertRef = ref)} />
      </View>
    );
  }

}
```